# GSettings / DConf settings not saved permanently

Tags: centos, dconf, gsettings

I have a problem with GSettings /Dconf on my Centos 7 + Gnome Classic box.

I'd like to turn the desktop animations off with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Everything works like a charm, but the value is being reverted to `true` on next login.

Same stuff goes for visual `dconf-editor`. Can't find any clue in the logs.

I've tried to delete `~/.config/dconf/user` file. No luck. The same stuff happens to the newly created user account.

Any suggestion how to debug?

Comment: This is a known bug in gnome < 3.12, see bug report [#705448](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705448) and bug report [#694692](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694692).

Comment: Have you seen this: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/custom-default-values-system-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for GNOME earlier than 3.11 (e.g. GNOME 3.8 in Ubuntu 14.04):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.remote-display active false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```